# How to efficiently handle missing data and calculate conditional statistics in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame df that contains some missing data in multiple columns. The structure of the DataFrame is as follows:

```
ID  Age  Gender  Score
1   25    Male    85.0
2   30  Female    90.0
3   22     NaN    78.0
4   27    Male     NaN
5   21  Female    80.0
```

How can I calculate the mean "Score" based on these age bins `['0-20', '21-25', '26-30', '31-40', '41+']`?

Comment: import pandas as pd
data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Age': [25, 30, 22, 27, 21],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', None, 'Male', 'Female'],
    'Score': [85.0, 90.0, 78.0, None, 80.0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the age bins and labels
age_bins = [0, 20, 25, 30, 40, float('inf')]
age_labels = ['0-20', '21-25', '26-30', '31-40', '41+']

# Bin the "Age" column
df['Age Group'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=age_bins, labels=age_labels)

# Calculate the mean "Score" for each age bin
mean_scores = df.groupby('Age Group')['Score'].mean()

print(mean_scores)

Comment: @Yax This is a comment. Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Age': [25, 30, 22, 27, 21],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', None, 'Male', 'Female'],
    'Score': [85.0, 90.0, 78.0, None, 80.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
age_bins = [0, 20, 25, 30, 40, float('inf')]
age_labels = ['0-20', '21-25', '26-30', '31-40', '41+']

df['AgeRange'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=age_bins, labels=age_labels)

mean_score_by_age_range = df.groupby('AgeRange')['Score'].mean()

print(mean_score_by_age_range)
```

output:

```
AgeRange
0-20      NaN
21-25    81.0
26-30    90.0
31-40     NaN
41+       NaN
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```